# How do I make a function convert its argument to a string

Tags: python, string, function, arguments

So I am trying to figure out how I can make a function take as input a sequence of characters, that are not defined as a string, and have it automatically interpret that as a string for instance:

```
def printstring(sequence_of_characters):
    a=str(sequence_of_characters)
    print(a)
```

Now when I run:

```
printstring(hello)
```

I expect the terminal to output:

```
'hello'
```

Instead it outputs

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
        printstring(hello)
NameError: name 'hello' is not defined
```

Now I realize that I can just call printstring on "hello", but I want the function to be able to take input that isn't already a string, and merely a sequence of chracters.

Comment: U should call as printstring("hello")

Comment: What @Srinath said, plus you can just `print(sequence_of_characters)`.

Comment: A sequence of characters is, by definition, a string.

Comment: The name `hello` isn't anything, it's undefined as the error message indicates. Basically it sounds like you want to know the name of the value the caller passed to the function (assuming there was one).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `sequence_of_characters` has to already be an object or variable. `hello` is just an unassigned variable. The only object that would work like you want would be some sort of number type like an `int` or `float` or `long`.

Basically, `hello` would have to have been a variable equal to a number to work. There is no way to get around not assigning it to something.

Comment: so is there no way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should call it with `printstring("hello")` with parentheses (never forget them)

It is 100% impossible for python to take an argument and print it without parentheses. If you do not include parentheses it will treat it like an object or method.

Because of this you're trying to assign a class to be a string.

So lets say you have a class.

```
class Hello:
    pass
```

you can't do

```
Hello = Hello()
```

It doesn't work like that instead.

```
def printstring(sequence_of_characters):
    sequence_of_characters=str(sequence_of_characters)
    print(sequence_of_characters)
```

becasue `sequence_of_characters` is string and all you are doing is reassigning it.

Comment: FYI: `String` is not an object.